# how to make '#box' draggable only by drag the '#head' div , not make the '#box' draggable when i drag '#content'

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag

this is my code :

```
<div id="box" style="border:1px solid red;height:100px;width:150px;position:relative;background:#eee">
        <div id="head" style="background:black">drag me</div>
        <div id="content" contenteditable=true style="border-bottom:1px solid red;height:70px;margin-bottom:5px;"> edit it </div>
        <input id="ok" type="button" value="ok"/>
        <input id="cancel" type="button" value="cancel"/>
    </div>
```

and the script is :

```
$('#box').draggable()
```

the demo is here :http://jsfiddle.net/VRxZe/

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#box').draggable({
    handle: $('#head')
});
```

Comment: @rockinthesixstring I don't think that was really what @zjm1126 was looking for. He was just trying to get the #head element only to be draggable, I don't think he just wanted a small piece of the #head to be draggable. Here is what I think he was asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/chromedude/VRxZe/5/

Comment: just showing the options... :p - there's all kinds of ways to make it happen.  I +1'd Harmen's answer cuz it's right.

Comment: also, that's why I didn't make it an answer. Just having fun.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring ok, got it.